# Como usar session para evitar que uma modal abra novamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um site em HTML, na index eu coloquei um modal para abrir assim que a pessoa entra, esse modal é para coletar o e-mail da pessoa, no entanto toda vez que a pessoa atualiza o site o modal volta a aparecer.
Gostaria de saber se tem como fazer algo usando javascript onde ele abrisse somente uma  vez, depois aparecer novamente só se o usuário fechar o navegador e voltar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem sim você pode utilizar [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage);

A lógica seria a seguinte, antes da modal abrir você pergunta:

```
 // É diferente de true?  <- nunca abriu?
if(!sessionStorage.getItem("abriu")){
   // Abra a modal
   sessionStorage.setItem("abriu",true); // na próxima vez ela não entrara na condição.
}
```

Comment: Gbrigado Gabriel, então dentro do if eu colocaria a função responsável por abril o modal?

Comment: @SérgioMachado isto !

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado Gabriel 
Abraços